# 405 “Method POST is not allowed” in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST framework to implement Get, Post api methods, and I got GET to work properly. However, when sending a post request, it's showing 405 error below. What am I missing here?

```
405 Method Not Allowed
{"detail":"Method \"POST\" not allowed."}
```

Sending this body via post method

```
{
    "title": "abc"
    "artist": "abc"
}
```

I have

api/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('api/(?P<version>(v1|v2))/', include('music.urls'))
]
```

music/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ListSongsView


urlpatterns = [
    path('songs/', ListSongsView.as_view(), name="songs-all")
]
```

music/views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Songs
from .serializers import SongsSerializer


class ListSongsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    Provides a get method handler.
    """
    queryset = Songs.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SongsSerializer
```

music/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Songs


class SongsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Songs
        fields = ("title", "artist")
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Songs(models.Model):
    # song title
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    # name of artist or group/band
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.title, self.artist)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class ListSongsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    Provides a get method handler.
    """
    queryset = Songs.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SongsSerializer
```

you need `ListCreateAPIView` as `ListView` has only `GET` method and doesnt allow `POST` method

Answer (score 0):

Good Day

generics.ListAPIView is not allowed to POST it is only GET. If you want to allow GET and POST. You can use generics.ListCreateAPIView heres the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview)

on your music/views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Songs
from .serializers import SongsSerializer


class ListSongsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    Provides a get method handler.
    """
    queryset = Songs.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SongsSerializer
```